# After installed Maven integration in Eclipse, how to create a Dynamic Web Project (RESTful Jersey project) which use Maven?

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, maven-2, jakarta-ee, jersey

I have installed **Maven integration** in my **Eclipse** Helios.

In **Eclipse**, I know how to create a RESTful Jersey project (dynamic web project) without using Maven.

But I do not know how to create a Maven based RESTful Jersey project (**Maven based Dynamic web project**) in **Eclipse** after I installed Maven integration.

Can someone tell me **how to create a Maven based RESTful Jersey project (or Dynamic Web project) in Eclipse?**

**File->New->Project->Maven->Maven project...then????**

Answer (score 0):

create a faceted project and choose dynamic web project, java,....
When the project ready do: right click, maven, enable dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial about this:
[How to build RESTful Service with Java using JAX-RS and Jersey (Example)](http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/)